# FindByView to get an EditText in a Button click method returns null

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, buttonclick

I've coded professionally for many many years in other languages, but I'm pretty new at Android and I'm learning a lot from sites like stack overflow.

After hours of searching I'm struggling with trying to get a reference to an EditText in a Button click method.  Both the EditText and Button are part of the same Activity.

Here's a cut down part of my activity_my.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/name" />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:id="@+id/save" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And a cut down part of my MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null));

        findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveClick(view);
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveClick(View view)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name); // this is always null
        if (editText != null)
        {
            String name = editText.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's because I'm trying to use the findViewById method on the view parameter.  I remember reading somewhere that the parameter to a button click event is the Button itself, not the layout.  If that's correct how do I get a reference to the layout in order to use the findViewById method?  Or is there something else wrong?

I've seen examples where the onClick event wraps an anonymous method where you can successfully use the findViewById because (I think) you are essentially nested in the onCreate event.  However, I'd like to keep my button click event as a separate (non-anonymous) method.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

to

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
```

and you can simply use

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
```

directly.

I guess EditText belongs to `activity_my.xml`

Also there is no need to initialize edittext everytime on button click

```
EditText editText;// declare as instance variable
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void saveClick(View view)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name); // this is always null
        if (editText != null)
        {
            String name = editText.getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

that returns a valid `View` (an `object != null`) only if the `EditText` is inside the `Button`. You should look for the `EditText` in the View's hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The `View.findViewById()` method looks for **child** views.

In your case, the findViewById call is in the onClickListener of your edittext view. This view does not have a child, it is simple an edittext. That's why you're getting null.